# Google Drive API (Javascript) - Can't download pdf file content from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, xmlhttprequest, google-drive-picker

I have an issue when trying to download a pdf file from Google Drive via the File Picker. My code works as expected with images and videos, but not pdf files. When downloading an image through the API `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file.id + '?alt=media';` i get the following response:

```
name: "Social-Facebook-Post-Cool-Down.png"
lastModified: 1578397749873
lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 07 2020 12:49:09 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
webkitRelativePath: ""
size: 317
type: ""
url: "blob:https://localhost:8080/647e4d15-d090-4c0f-aa3e-bd7481f11043"
```

But when calling the same url with a pdf file id, I don't the get url property and thereby not the file content. So when opening the downloaded pdf file, it is just empty/blank. What am I missing here?

This is my code for downloading the file content:

```
for (let file of files) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var getUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file.id + '?alt=media';
  xhr.open("GET", getUrl, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.googleDriveToken);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
    let fileObj = new File([bytes], file.name);
    googleFiles.push(fileObj);
    counter++;
    if (counter == files.length) {
      this.$emit('filesAdded', googleFiles);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you try adding a `mimeType` parameter like this : `'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file.id + '?alt=media&mimeType=application/pdf'`

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. If I create a blob with the bytes from the file and add that to my File object, it works. 
    `var blob = new Blob([bytes]);
    fileObj.url = blob;`

Comment: Setting the `responseType` here is VERY important. If you use google.drive API you also need to do this for the `get` command.

Answer (score 0):

As OP figured out, creating a blob with the bytes from the file and adding them to the File object fixed the issue:

```
var blob = new Blob([bytes]); 
fileObj.url = blob;
```

Referencing the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files):

> *Blob*
>
> A file that contains text or binary content such as images, videos, and PDFs.